# How to avoid "command not found" in a bash parameter expansion?

Tags: bash

I wrote the following bash script:

```bsh
${MY_FLAG:=true}
${LOG_FILE:="something.log"}
```

I am trying to assign `true` to MY_FLAG and the string `"something.log"` to LOG_FILE. I use parameter expansions because I want to set these variables only if they were not set already.

The problem is that MY_FILE becomes true but LOG_FILE throws an error:

```
script.sh: line 2: something.log: command not found
```

I could not find a way to assign the string as is, I tried with different options, simple quotes, and echoing it but nothing did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters will always expand to a value, so you'll have to use them in a context where such an argument is ignored. Conveniently,  `:` aka `true` does this:

```
: "${LOG_FILE:="something.log"}"
```

It only happens to work for your `${MY_FLAG:=true}` because `true` (as discussed) is a valid command. If you run the script with `MY_FLAG=date ./yourscript` then you'll see that it actually runs `date` instead of just assigning a default.